# Can I define a function in Java ouside the class

Tags: java

I have declared a function in a class and want to know if I could define it outside the class. I have seen these cases in C++ but haven't come across anything like this in Java. Does Java allows doing this?

Comment: Everything in Java needs to be inside a class

Comment: @CoryRoy interface too? :P

Comment: @alfasin You are correct, class or interface.

Comment: @alfasin enum also,trolling :D

Comment: @KumarAbhinav if you want to be a *real* wiseass you should say that it doesn't apply to a... class, as well :)))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No you can't.

Java requires a single top level class for each file (eg. `class Foo` in `Foo.java`), named as the file. Everything must reside inside that class.

Answer (score 1):

> I have declared a function in a class and want to know if I could define it outside the class. I have seen these cases in C++ but haven't come across anything like this in Java. Does Java allows doing this?

No, you can't do that outside a class. This is similar as asking whether we can write some codes without a class at all. Everything is done within a class in Java.

If no class exist, then at least it will be an interface.

**Example**:

```
class{
    void method(){}
}

interface{
    void methodA();
    default void method(){}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Everyone above is right, the function will be out of scope in java, in c++ you can declare functions as global and such, but java everything has to be inside of the class, unless you are working with an interface